# How to permamently change partition attributes?

Tags: restore, mount, partitions

I've a rooted phone. I want `/system` partition to be `rw` on every boot. Partition's attribues are defined in `/fstab.<model_name>` file. It seems that this file gets restored to the original version after each reboot -- my changes are discarded by the OS. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Have you tried modifying `/system/etc/vold.fstab` instead? I believe that is loaded on boot.

Comment: @Chahk: I don't have this file on my device.

Comment: Must be for older Android OS versions then. Are you running 4.4+?

Comment: @Chahk: <4.3 ver.